# How do I run R programs from Sublime text 2 in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, programming, text-editor, sublime-text, r

I have R programming environment in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I also have Sublime Text 2 and I want to run R programs in it. I don't have any IDE like RStudio and even I dont want to use them as I am just a novice in R programming. So please suggest me a method to run R programs directly from Sublime Text 2.

Comment: How do you run it from command-line?

Comment: I type R in the terminal. Then R shell opens up in the terminal and I do a bit of programming stuff there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with R, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18306656/1329116), you run a script from command-line using [Rscript](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/Rscript.html). With Rscript installed, you can then create a custom [build system](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/configuration.html) for Sublime Text (`Tools > Build System > New Build System`). At its most basic, it would look something like this:

```
{
  "cmd": ["Rscript", "$file"],
  "selector": "source.r, source.R",
  "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
}
```

Now, you can build your R script by pressing <kbd>F7</kbd> or from `Tools > Build`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! It worked nicely. But in the output console, I am unable to give any input from the user. Can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: That's not possible in the console, but I *think* [SublimeREPL](https://sublimerepl.readthedocs.io) lets you do that.

Comment: Ok! Well thanks a lot for your help! I will use SublimeREPL for R programming.